# C# EPPlus problem with reading CSV file to DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, csv, epplus

I have a specific CSV file without ending empty separators:

```
1;AAAA
2;BB;CC;DD;EE;~
```

And when I read file:

```
var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader(myStream, new ExcelReaderConfiguration()
{
    AutodetectSeparators = new char[] { ',', ';', '\t', '|', '#' },
});
var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
{
    ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
    {
        UseHeaderRow = false,
    }
};

var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(conf);
wire = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

I have only one cell in row. Not two for first line or four for second line, split by `;`.

```
1;AAAA;;;;
2;BB;CC;DD;EE;~;;;
```

Missing `;;;` was a problem.
Is any way to read CSV without ending separators?

Comment: It's not a CSV if the separators are missing, it's a jagged flat file. EPPlus is primarily an Excel generation library, not a complex flat file reader. You may be able to use CsvHelper   to handle jagged files, by specifying what to do about missing fields. You'll probably have to specify the fields in advance though

Comment: If the file has a different quantity of separated lines, how are you be able to sure which line is first or second or,..etc? For example, "AAAA" is the second column or not?